# Implementing FIFO behaviour in a hashset

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, hashset

I have a requirement in which each element in a collection must be unique and for that purpose i have used a hashset.

I however also want to remove elements from the hashset based on First In First Our order. However the default Hashset DataStructure in .NET doesn't have this behaviour.

Is there any way to extend hashset to implement this behaviour or should i some other data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pair the hash set with a queue. The hash set will give you O(1) complexity to test whether the element is in the queue and the queue will give you first in first out behavior, also in O(1)

If you're storing reference types the extra space overhead of using the two data structures would be minimal (double the number of references).

If you are using value types a self-balancing binary search tree would give you look-up and insertion in O(log n) but would allow you to store only one copy of each element.

Comment: @JimMischel that's what I meant. The storage space for references.

Comment: The data to be stored is string.

Comment: In .NET, strings are reference types. See Jon Skeet's post here for a quick tutorial on strings: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/strings.aspx

Comment: I am having problem pairing hashset with a queue because regardless of the order of the pairing i still need an item to be removed from hashset and the nature of my program only allows me to know the order of the elements to be removed not the exact elements.

Comment: @WinCoder Every time you add an item you need to first check the hashset, and if it's non-empty then add the item to both.  When you go to remove an item from the queue also remove it from the set.  You can use the set alone to implement contains.  Viola, you're done.

Comment: @Servy pretty much beat me to it but I was going to say the same thing.. Basically whenever you dequeue an element from the queue you also remove it from the hash set.

Comment: Sorry My Bad. I am a dumb, lazy programmer never thought of using a custom collection. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Extending the HS is impossible. You could try with the [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx). You put `null` in the Value and use only the `Key`. It's accessible both by `Key` and by insertion order. Sadly it isn't strongly typed (it's from the .NET 1.1 era... Technically it's from .NET 2.0, but clearly it was designed prior to the creation of generics).

```
OrderedDictionary myOrderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey1", null);
myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey2", null);
myOrderedDictionary.Add("keyToDelete", null);
myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey3", null);

// Remove first
myOrderedDictionary.RemoveAt(0);

// Check for existance
if (myOrderedDictionary.Contains("something")) {
}
```

Comment: In addition, removing will most likely be O(N).

Comment: @JimMischel It could be `O(1)` and enumeration by FIFO be `O(N)` (it could keep two full dictionaries inside, one by key and one by index)... There are various ways it could be built. MSDN doesn't tell.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` isn't the right thing to use here.

[Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) or an extension of it would be your best bet.

Comment: A queue is *the* FIFO data structure, but it's no good at de-duplication, so you only shifted which half of the problem is unsolved.